# Android set color and listner on part of text

Tags: android, xml, text, colors, textview

Suppose I have TextView and I want to change color of some part in it. Like this

[image]

And I must set OnclickListener on text " **Terms Of Use** ", so How can I do that but using two textViews. Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple Checkbox with no text, and for text clicking event 
this is what you are looking for [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can youse HTML in TextView:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Test</h2>"));
```