# Seeking the Simplest way to have a TextView's text colored in diffrent colors

Tags: android

I want to have some of the string that is shown by a text view to be red, and some black, how can i do that?

is there a way to mention it simply on the XML file? (strings.xml)

Comment: Maybe answers from [here][1] can help you.

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686842/android-set-color-and-listner-on-part-of-text

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use span. [Text Style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html)

For Example,

```
   final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(" text must be here ");
   final ForegroundColorSpan fc1 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
   final ForegroundColorSpan fc2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255)); 
   sb.setSpan(fc1 , 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
   sb.setSpan(fc2, 5, 8, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
   yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

(or)

In styles XML, declare the color values as shown below

```
<color name="redColor">#ff0000</color>
```

and use it in the layout xml, for the textColor attribute,

```
android:textColor="@color/redColor"
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the xml values to color the same string.Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this,

```
String.replaceAll(textToHighlight,<font color="red">textToHighlight</font>);

Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(String));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way of doing it is to use a spanned type as below.

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextview);
String firstName = "FirstName";
String lastName = "LastName";
Spanned details = Html.fromHtml(firstName + "<br />" + "<small><font color=\"#767676\">" + lastName + "</b></small>");
textview.setText(details);
```

Hope this helps